# "MySQL server has gone away" error while logging into phpmyadmin on google cloud sql

Tags: google-app-engine, phpmyadmin, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to install phpMyAdmin onto google cloud sql. I have followed the steps mentioned here https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/phpmyadmin-on-app-engine

It says that I should login using username as root and password as null. But I am getting the error  "#2006 - MySQL server has gone away" when I try to login with username and password.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the instruction and it went fine for me. I found that if you enter a wrong MySQL instance name, you would get that error. Can you double check the instance name? It should be something like "your-project-id:instance-name"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem! As Herman mentioned you need the correct connection string so to find this correctly you can click on your cloud SQL instance and you should find your full connection string.

[image]